# I am unable to run bundle install on `CircleCi`

Tags: installation, bundle, circleci

[image]

I really don't know but my test runs fine locally when I push circleci is unable to run bundle install.

Comment: More information including the OS version you are using, the intended version of Ruby (2.3.1?), and as much of `circle.yml` as you're willing to share will really be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to configure `circle.yml` in your project and specify `bundler` as dependency.
Ref: https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/configuration/#dependencies

Try this: (in the example below, i'm using the latest version of bundler)

```
dependencies:
  pre:
   - gem install bundler -v 1.14.5
```